Nextjs server side logging in production mode
I have a nextjs 14 project which is using server side rendering, I have added both console.log and Winston logger in my server components and both the logs are displayed when I run npm run build.
However, when I run npm run build, the logs will come out, but when I run npm run start, no log will be displayed. It seems like the logs only appear in development mode and build time.
Same goes to my Linux server, after I deployed my project using nginx and pm2, I can't see my console logs in pm2 logs and Winston logs are not written into the file.
Please help on this and let me know why the logs are not showing in production runtime.

I haven't tried it out, but maybe this blog can help you (although it was written for NextJS 13): https://dev.to/abhijitdotsharma/production-essentials-logging-in-nextjs-13-43l0.

You are probably using static rendering instead of dynamic rendering. You have the following options to declare your server components as dynamic:

Using cookies() or headers(). Using these in a server component will opt the whole route into dynamic rendering at request time.

Using the searchParams prop in a server component page will opt the whole route into dynamic rendering at request time.

Provide a route segment configuration with the value force-dynamic inside your layout or page component depending on the desired scope.


Keep in mind that inside the app router your server components are only rendered at build time by default and saved as static html instead of being compiled per request like when using getServerSideProps inside of the pages router.
